# How to get location and rotation object

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm working on a script that makes a rigid body simulation, I'm interested to get the final position and rotation of my objects but I have not idea how to do considering that I'm pretty new in the using bpy. Anyone has an idea how to code it? To be clear on the data that I wanna get i'll achieve a screenshot from blender panel. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The data is utilized to establish the starting point of the object. When using constraints or rigid body physics, these values are employed to populate a transform matrix that is utilized in simulations. To obtain the transform matrix, use either the `matrix_world` or `matrix_local` (if related to a parent). The values can be accessed using `translation` and `to_euler()` methods.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects["Your object name"]
print(obj.matrix_world.translation)
print(obj.matrix_world.to_euler())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your suggested code works but at this point the problem is that, when I run the code on Blender I get different results than I run the code from, for example, the command prompt and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you sure that Rigid body sim has been run or baked?

Comment: Yes I am, I've checked on Blender and the simulation has been run.

Comment: I fixed the problem, basically the solution was to run the script on Blender because when I run it on visual studio code the rigid body simulation didn't bake.